# ESP32 adding <app-content> and <style> to my page

Tags: html, server

I'm creating WebSerwer on ESP32 to create dashboard. Im using WebServer.h, ESPmDNS.h and WebSocketsServer.h

`

```
void setupServer(std::string ssid, std::string password)
{
    WiFi.begin(ssid.c_str(), password.c_str());

    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }

    Serial.print("connected\n");
    Serial.print("IP address: ");
    Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());

    if (!MDNS.begin("esp32")) {
        Serial.println("Error setting up MDNS responder!");
        while (1) {
            delay(1000);
        }
    }
    Serial.println("mDNS responder started");
    // server.on("/", []() {
    //     server.send_P(200, "text/html", webpage123);
    // });
    SPIFFS.begin();
    server.on("/", serveIndexFile);
    //server.on("/index.css", serveIndexCssFile);
    server.begin();
    webSocket.begin();
    webSocket.onEvent(webSocketEvent);
```

`
method that send source files from flash:

```
void serveIndexFile() {
    File file = SPIFFS.open("/index.html", "r");
    server.streamFile(file, "text/html");
    file.close();
}
```

and even with completly empty .html file after I inspect page i get something like this:
[image]

Could someone explain what is it and what causes this?

I tried to open this side on my phone and it doesnt showing up, so i think it may be caused by some extansion on my browser

Answer (score 0):

ok nevermind, I check every extansion and letyshops(cashback) was adding  to every page and opera adblock added styles

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).